# Anti hacking android project

Tags: android, security, memory-safety

I need more information about how to enable my project to not be hacked. 1st: yes I know that you need a rooted device to hack games and app on your phone. 2nd: yes I know this is more into memory reading and adjustments like cheat engine.

I need to know or even some info into how to do it. If you are familiar with the Japanese made game "Battle Cats", you would also know that trying to do a memory scan would result in the game instantly going into a browser change and then trying to connect to a certain API that reports the user.

I wanted to know how it was possible and how I can make something like this, as this is for a better security details that I know that the Japanese have already done and I need something like this to further my project's security.

If you know anything, please give me some information.

Also yes I have tried to do this in Google and all I get is anti-virus for Android / mobile devices, which is a bit frustrating to say the least.

Answer (score 4):

The, thing you are talking about in more generalized way is called **Reverse Engineering** , which is almost impossible to get rid of, but apart from that there are some other ways too, to hijack the data transfered by your device to external network(Web), even though if you are using SSL(HTTPS), this can be done using all famous attack called **MITM** and it can be achieved using tool mitmproxy, the security researchers always finds out some way to break into the system, so what your question pointing is almost impossible to do,

Here are few methods you can try:

- Use obfuscation and tools like ProGuard.
- Encrypt some part of source and data.
- Use a proprietary inbuilt checksum in the app to detect tempering.
- Introduce code to avoid loading in a debugger, that is, let the app
  have the ability to detect the debugger and exit / kill the debugger.
- Seperate the authentication as an online service.
- Use application diversity
- Use the finger printing technique for e.g., hardware signatures of
  the devices from different subsystem before authenticating the
  device.

Comment: let me e more specific, i have a mobile phone , note 2 , rooted, i use gameCIH which is like cheat engine for PC but this is for mobile.  then i then in turn open a game , and then use the gameCIH which you need to input the number that you need to search or looking for , where in which the app would search for the data that was in the memory and then i play the game more to change the value , and adjust the value again , search , and then when i find the value change it to what i want , then viola! its changed..... no internet, works on encrypted data as well.... it have tried it as well

Comment: but other info that you have added is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are absolutely correct, but the think you did is in the context of rooted device. Even though there are some app's which lets you hijack the data transfered in between apps intent, but what I mentioned in answer, is the fact whether the device is rooted or not, and of course in case of rooted device you have entire control of what apps are doing, etc. But one can take above measures to reduce down the possibility of reverse engineering, or even intermediate data hijacking, using some proprietary encryption's, using which it will difficult to do what you did with that game :)

Comment: thank you for the input , because i am still doing a bit more research and trying to get data from people that have normal phones and rooted phones trying to get atleast 5k answers from random people in the streets its a bit hard to do , but every info helps thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can get the help of [proguard](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html) for android. ProGuard is free to use.

> ProGuard is a free Java class file shrinker, optimizer, obfuscator, and preverifier. It detects and removes unused classes, fields, methods, and attributes. It optimizes bytecode and removes unused instructions. It renames the remaining classes, fields, and methods using short meaningless names. Finally, it preverifies the processed code for Java 6 or higher, or for Java Micro Edition.

[Here is the official documentation for ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)

[There are so many examples are provided here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html)

Another option is to use [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/dexguard).

> DexGuard provides advanced security features tailor-made for the Android operating system. It offers protection against static analysis. DexGuard shields your apps from cloning, tampering, key extraction and piracy, by applying multiple techniques such as string encryption, class encryption, asset encryption, call hiding, code obfuscation and resource obfuscation.

Comment: thanks for the info ill also check this out